# convert timestamp string to timestamp integer php

Tags: php

Here is my php code

```
var_dump($args['startdate']); 
var_dump((int)$args['startdate']);die();
```

Here is output

```
string(13) "1468821556126" int(2147483647)
```

Expected output

```
string(13) "1468821556126" int(1468821556126)
```

Why this is happening and how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What's the issue? What does *"resolve"* mean in this context?

Comment: `int idate ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`  read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php

Comment: @BeetleJuice See edit now...

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks. I understand now. I've written an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a reliable result because your number is too large to be represented as an integer.

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX; //2147483647 on my system
```

For a number as large as yours, if you need it in numerical format, cast it to a float instead of an integer

```
echo floatval('1468821556126'); //1.46882155613E+12
```

From there, if you're trying to get a date, I assume that this is Javascript time, which is in milliseconds. To convert to a Unix Timestamp, you'll then need to divide it by 1000.

Comment: It is working.. thanks for the answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a 32bit system. The number you're seeing is the maximum size of an int on a 32 bit machine. 
Use float or change to a 64bit machine.

Ref: [PHP Integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: How can i get desired output ?? i know what you are saying already... :)

Comment: Could you provide a little more context as to why you need integer? PHP is very flexible when it comes to data type. More often than not, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you cannot get exactly `int(1468821556126)` from a `var_dump` because PHP integers don't go that high.  Cast to a float instead as I do in my solution (or as is suggested on this one)

Comment: @adarshdec23 i just want date from it...

Comment: @adarshdec23 `echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($args['startdate']));` output was `1970-01-01`.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because your `$args['startdate']` is in miliseconds, you need to divide it by 1000

Comment: If `$args['startdate']` is a timestamp then this is the only correct answer. `echo(date("Y-m-d H:i:s e", 1468821556126/1000));` prints `2016-07-18 08:59:16 Europe/Bucharest`.

Comment: @axiac This is probably what the op is looking for.